# FTP client that can also sudo chown

Tags: ftp, ssh

Filezilla has been my FTP client of choice for over a decade.  Unfortunately (because reasons), I now need an FTP client that will let me change the owner/group of a file easily, I'm sick of wasting time puttying in to do it.

It needs to sudo chown.  (I tried working around it with Filezilla's chmod, but it doesn't prepend sudo, so fails.) Suggestions?

Comment: For what OS? Budget?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this will work. Usually sudo will ask for the password before it can do its action and there is no kind of terminal functionality in the FTP protocol which could be used to transfer this password prompt to the user of Filezilla or other FTP clients and back.

If there is no password prompt then you might use the SITE command of the FTP protocol which could be used to execute arbitrary commands. Of course this command must be available in the FTP server and the server must be configured to accept your sudo commands as valid commands, which I doubt.

Comment: I don't think it is an impossible request. A program could act as a FTP+SSH client. At first connection it would ask for both FTP and SSH credentials/settings, then depending on the action it would use one or the other.